# Create DotCMIS IContentStream from local file?

Tags: dotcmis

How to create a [DotCMIS.Data.IContentStream](http://dotnetinside.com/en/type/DotCMIS/IContentStream/0.6.0.0) object from a local file?

The tutorial only describes how to create one from a byte array in memory:

```
byte[] content = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");
ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStream();
contentStream.FileName = "hello-world.txt";
contentStream.MimeType = "text/plain";
contentStream.Length = content.Length;
contentStream.Stream = new MemoryStream(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stream is actually the standard [System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) of .NET, so here is how to create a DotCMIS IContentStream from a local file:

```
ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStream();
contentStream.FileName = "hello-world.txt";
contentStream.MimeType = "text/plain";
contentStream.Stream = File.Open("hello-world.txt", FileMode.Open);
contentStream.Length = contentStream.Stream.Length;
```